# How do inline anonymous classes in regard with local variables work in backround?

Tags: java, anonymous-class

let's say we have the following classes:

```
public class Foo {

    private final List<String> myFooList;

    public Foo(BarHelper barHelper) {
        myFooList = barHelper.getMyList();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FooListRepository fooListRepository = new FooListRepository();
        Foo myFoo = new Foo(new BarHelper() {
            @Override
            public List<String> getMyList() {
                return fooListRepository.getList();
            }
        });

        System.out.println(myFoo.getMyFooList().toString());
    }

    public List<String> getMyFooList() {
        return myFooList;
    }

}

interface BarHelper {
    List<String> getMyList();
}

public class FooListRepository {

    private List<String> myBarList;

    public FooListRepository() {
        //initilize myBarList
    }

    public List<String> getList() {
        return myBarList;
    }
}
```

How would really internally the anonymous class in the main method work?

As with java documentation there would be a new class compiled, but the question is how would `myTestList` be handled?
Would java somehow save it in the anonymous class as an internal variable?

What really hapens in backround in this line `System.out.println(myFoo.getMyFooList().toString());`

Does Java call `FooListRepository`  in backround somehow ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's part of the Oracle tutorials for anonymous classes. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html#accessing

Comment: See this answer of the linked dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53203670/1898563

Comment: Hi @Michael thanks for your suggestions, but I couldn't find any answer in the link you send me (stackoverflow.com/a/53203670/1898563), the question is a bit specific about final variables and goes not generally how anonymous classes handle local variables. Perhaps I read something wrong ?